# Is it possible to find out when the ANGULAR 2+ project was build in component?

Tags: angular, angular8

I would like to tag a field with the datetime the angular project was built.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: "diagnostics",
  template: "<h2>Build when: {{buildWhen}}</h2>"
})
export class DiagnosticsComponent implements OnInit {
  buildWhen: string = "";

  constructor(private dp: DatePipe) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const buildTime = `Where to get the datetime ????`;
    this.buildWhen = this.dp.transform(buildTime, "full");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think [APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER) might be useful

Answer (score 1):

I have the following in my environment.prod.ts

```
buildTime: 'TBA'
```

I use a package called replace-in-file and the script

```
var replace = require('replace-in-file');
var moment = require('moment');

const buildTime = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A');

const options = {
  files: 'src/environments/environment.prod.ts',
  from: /buildTime: '(.*)'/g,
  to: "buildTime: '" + buildTime + "'",
  allowEmptyPaths: false,
};

try {
  let changedFiles = replace.sync(options);
  if (changedFiles == 0) {
    throw "Please make sure that file '" + options.files + "' has \"version: ''\"";
  }
  console.log('Build time: ' + buildTime);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error occurred:', error);
  throw error
}
```

and use the build command

```
node ./replace.build-time.js && ng build --prod
```

Then you can use

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

buildTime = environment.buildTime;
```